# (It's a duplicate) How to access to a PHP proprety, especially protected proprety

Tags: php, traits

I need your help.
I need to acces to an object proprety. This proprety is in an array and it's protected.
I'm working wtih a third library that generate me the object, so I can't create getter and setter.
So I need your help to figure out what to do.

```
Array
(
[0] => Media Object
(
[context:protected] => 0
[contextId:protected] =>
[properties:protected] => Array
(
[source-width] => 1920
[source-height] => 1080
[source-duration] => 166
[source-filesize] => 12155636
[source-orientation] => 0
```

It's the source-duration proprety that I want. Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there maybe a getter already?

Comment: There is no getter already